# FTL tags not processing inside Iframe

Tags: java, iframe, struts2, freemarker

I am using Freemarker(FTL) pages for my UI and using struts 2. Now on success of my action, I am calling a ftl page that consist of two Iframe which themselves are ftl pages. Problem is
1) FTL tags inside the corresponding Iframe ftl page are not getting processed.
Although If i dont use iframe and just put content as it is,ftl tags are getting processed.
I am really not sure why this is happening.
Here is my ftl page that gets called on action success

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blue Black</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.css">

</head>

<body>
<iframe src="BlueBlackMenu.ftl" style="border:0;position:absolute;top:0%;left:0;width:15%;height:100%;"></iframe>
<iframe src="NewClientDetail.ftl" style="border:0;position:absolute;top:0%;left:15%;width:85%;height:100%;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Now suppose inside NewClientDetail.ftl i have a tag like this

```
<input type="text" value="${clientVO.companyName?if_exists}" id="companyNameId" />
```

It is not processing this ftl tag under value attribute and is displaying on screen as it is.

Comment: I'm surprised it renders anything at all, actually. Iframes are expected to be complete requests, not templates.

Comment: @DaveNewton thats what.. if i put ftl content outside iframe then its rendering..but inside iframe its not..... can u tel me the reason

Comment: What do you mean, "outside iframe"? How? In any case, I pretty much told you already: an iframe is expected to be a complete URL, e.g., rendered by an action.

Comment: <body>
 <input type="text" value="${loginVO.userName?if_exists}"  />
<iframe src="BlueBlackMenu.ftl" style="border:0;position:absolute;top:0%;left:0;width:15%;height:100%;"></iframe>
<iframe src="NewClientDetail.ftl" style="border:0;position:absolute;top:0%;left:15%;width:85%;height:100%;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

Now what i wanna say is input tag will process if its not inside the iframe..although if i use the same input tag inside iframe, the ftl part is not rendering

Comment: ... And I told you why. What I asked is how you were "including" it *outside* the iframe. I don't know how else I can say it so you'll understand.

Comment: so is there anyway using which i can render my freemarker content inside a iframe..because thats my requirement..sorry i am new to this so all these questions

Comment: Call an action that renders it.

Comment: Also, the fact that one can download a raw `ftl` file from your server is a bit worrisome. After all the raw ftl is source code. Either put them on a non-public place (like inside `WEB-INF`), or block access to `*.ftl` resources in `web.xml` via `security-constraint`. I'm not sure which is the Struts-ish way though.